# Unable to run couchbase on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: virtual-machine, ubuntu-16.04, couchbase

I tried to install all the couchbase using all the methods provided in the couchbase website documentation but still facing errors.
The Debian file is loading continuously and if I'm trying to install it using terminal, I'm getting the following error.

> E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
>   E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if there is a dpkg process running, `ps afx|grep dpkg`

If thats the case, kill it with `sudo killall dpkg`

Remove the lock file with `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`

That should do the trick